# is it fine to mix different sizes of memory devices on servers

Tags: memory, dell

I have Dell 00NH4P Server.

```
dmidecode -t16
Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
Maximum Capacity: 288 GB
Error Information Handle: Not Provided
Number Of Devices: 18
```

and

```
dmidecode -t17 | grep -i size
Size: 4096 MB
Size: 4096 MB
Size: No Module Installed
Size: 4096 MB
Size: 4096 MB
Size: No Module Installed
Size: No Module Installed
Size: No Module Installed
Size: No Module Installed
Size: 4096 MB
Size: 4096 MB
Size: No Module Installed
Size: 4096 MB
Size: 4096 MB
Size: No Module Installed
Size: No Module Installed
Size: No Module Installed
Size: No Module Installed
```

now i am planning to install 48 extra memory, is it fine to install 3 items (16G for each) or 6 items (8 G for each) while i have 8 items installed already (4G each)... does this affect my server, or in other words will they be functioning fine? or i have to install 12 items (4G each)
Please Advise.

Comment: Check the server specs. If that doesn't answer your question contact Dell support.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the server (especially on the CPUs you installed) and the RAM-channels the server offers. Generally the slots should be filled equal on every channel - you´ll have at least 2 or 4 channels for RAM. So chosing 3 or 6 is no good idea. The channels should be filled equally - so you should place 4 or 8 equal DRAM items.